# How to extract data from multiple .TXT file and store to variables

Tags: javascript, read-text

I am new to JS and I want to store the data of several .TXT files in variables (ARRAY).

Here is the structure of the .TXT files:
MONTH;YEAR;CUSTOMER

Here is the code that I modified. 
The alert contains the correct data but not the variables.

```
<input type="file" id="fileinput" multiple />
<script type="text/javascript">
function readMultipleFiles(evt) {
//Retrieve all the files from the FileList object
var files = evt.target.files;
var Statement_Fname =[] ;
var statement_Month=[];
var statement_Year =[];
var statement_client=[];

    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
        Statement_Fname[i] = files[i].name
        var r = new FileReader();
            r.onload = (function (f) {
                                        return function (e) {
                                            var contents = e.target.result;
                                            var splt = contents.split(";")
                                            statement_Month[i] = splt[0];
                                                statement_year[i] = splt[1];
                                            statement_client[i] = splt[2]; 
                                            alert(contents);
                                                            };
                                    }   )(f);
                                        r.readAsText(f);
                                        }
}
document.getElementById('fileinput').addEventListener('change', 
readMultipleFiles, false);
</script>
```

Comment: Can you `console.log` the contents (pun intended) of the `contents` variable, then share (a small part of) it with us please

Comment: Sure, I break the code just after the line "var contents = e.target.result;" and console.log(contents) result is 
MARS;2018;MONACO

Comment: Yes, I will have to open several files organized the same way. I want to store for each file : Fname[i],  a sub variable with the data of the .TXT inside:
Fname[1] = "data1.txt" Month[1] = March Year[1] = 2018 client[1]= Monaco
Fname[2] = "data2.txt" Month[2] = June Year[2] = 2015 client[2]= Switzerland